# How would you simplify this c# statement?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I know there has to be a simpler way of writing this expression. I am not able to figure out how however.

```
if (order != null)
{
    name += " " + order + extension;
}
else
{
    name += extension;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Try this : name += (order != null) ? " " + order + extension : extension;

Comment: It´s not that hard to google a bit for ternary operator or if you don´t know this term just something similar as "short version for if else". And if you found that it *is* the ternary operator you´ll find a duplicate here on SO quite soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator:

```
name+= (order == null) ? extension : " " + order + extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for your question considering code quality and readability. You do not need an if-else condition.

```
name += string.IsNullOrEmpty(order) ? extension : " " + order + extension;
```

Comment: You're assuming `order` is a string. It might not be.

Comment: @JamesJenkinson Yes. i wanted to mention it in my answer that i am assuming that order and extension are strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C#6 you can also use string interpolation:

```
name += (order != null) ? " {order}{extension}" : extension;
```

Looks a bit neater I think.